# Flink Python Datastream API Kafka Producer Sink Serializaion

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I'm trying to read data from one kafka topic and writing to another after making some processing.
I'm able to read data and process it when i try to write it to another topic. it gives the error

If I try to write the data as it is without doing any processing over it. Kafka producer `SimpleStringSchema` accepts it.
But I want to convert String to JSON. play with JSON and then write it to another topic in String format.

My Code:

```
import json

from pyflink.common import Row
from pyflink.common.serialization import SimpleStringSchema, SerializationSchema,JsonRowSerializationSchema,Encoder
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types,BasicType,TypeInformation,BasicTypeInfo
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import FlinkKafkaConsumer, FlinkKafkaProducer


def my_map(obj):
    json_obj = json.loads(json.loads(obj))
    return json.dumps(json_obj["name"])


def utf8_decoder(s):
    """ Decode the unicode as UTF-8 """
    if s is None:
        return None
    return s.decode('utf-8')


def datastream_api_demo():
    # 1. create a StreamExecutionEnvironment
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    # the sql connector for kafka is used here as it's a fat jar and could avoid dependency issues
    env.add_jars("file:///Users/niaz/Downloads/f2.jar")

    # 2. create source DataStream
    deserialization_schema = SimpleStringSchema()

    # deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder() \
    #     .type_info(type_info=Types.ROW([
    #         Types.("name", Types.STRING()),
    #         Types.FIELD("age", Types.LONG()),
    #         Types.FIELD("car", Types.STRING())])).build()

    kafka_source = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
        topics='test_source_topic_input',
        deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
        properties={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'test_group'})

    ds = env.add_source(kafka_source)
    ds = ds.map(lambda a: my_map(a))

    # 3. define the execution logic
    # ds = ds.map(lambda a: Row(a % 4, 1), output_type=Types.ROW([Types.LONG(), Types.LONG()])) \
    #        .key_by(lambda a: a[0]) \
    #        .reduce(lambda a, b: Row(a[0], a[1] + b[1]))

    # 4. create sink and emit result to sink
    serialization_schema = SimpleStringSchema()
    kafka_sink = FlinkKafkaProducer(
        topic='test_sink_topic_4',
        serialization_schema=serialization_schema,
        producer_config={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'test_group'})
    ds.add_sink(kafka_sink)
    #ds.print()
    # 5. execute the job
    env.execute('datastream_api_demo')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    datastream_api_demo()
```

And I'm getting following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o0.execute.
: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:137)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:237)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:1081)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:264)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:572)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:22)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:21)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:436)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:435)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:216)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:206)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:197)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:682)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:435)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.AsynchronousException: Caught exception while processing timer.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$StreamTaskAsyncExceptionHandler.handleAsyncException(StreamTask.java:1309)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.handleAsyncException(StreamTask.java:1285)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invokeProcessingTimeCallback(StreamTask.java:1424)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$null$16(StreamTask.java:1413)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMailsWhenDefaultActionUnavailable(MailboxProcessor.java:344)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:681)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeInvoke(StreamTask.java:636)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:620)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:779)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: TimerException{org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator}
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:26)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.PythonMapOperator.emitResult(PythonMapOperator.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.emitResults(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:299)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.invokeFinishBundle(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:322)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.checkInvokeFinishBundleByTime(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:314)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.lambda$open$0(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:133)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invokeProcessingTimeCallback(StreamTask.java:1422)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class java.lang.String ([B and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema.serialize(SimpleStringSchema.java:36)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaSerializationSchemaWrapper.serialize(KafkaSerializationSchemaWrapper.java:71)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.invoke(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:907)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.invoke(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.invoke(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:223)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:54)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:71)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved it by providing the output type as Java string which was like

```
 from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
 ds = ds.map(lambda a: my_map(a),Types.STRING()) # Map function needs ouput type to serialize it to Java String
```

Comment: This is what worked for me after trying so many things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG and ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG in producer_config in FlinkKafkaProducer

props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");

Comment: Hi @ChangLi thank you for your response. but i'm getting following error after adding these configs `Invalid value org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer for configuration key.serializer: Class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer could not be found.`