# Flink Python Datastream API Kafka Consumer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, stream-processing, data-stream

Im new to pyflink. Im tryig to write a python program to read data from kafka topic and prints data to stdout. I followed the link [Flink Python Datastream API Kafka Producer Sink Serializaion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156114/flink-python-datastream-api-kafka-producer-sink-serializaion). But i keep seeing NoSuchMethodError due to version mismatch. I have added the flink-sql-kafka-connector available at https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11/1.13.0/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.13.0.jar. Can someone help me in with a proper example to do this? Following is my code

```
import json
import os

from pyflink.common import SimpleStringSchema
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import FlinkKafkaConsumer
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types


def my_map(obj):
    json_obj = json.loads(json.loads(obj))
    return json.dumps(json_obj["name"])


def kafkaread():
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()

    env.add_jars("file:///automation/flink/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.10.1.jar")

    deserialization_schema = SimpleStringSchema()

    kafkaSource = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
        topics='test',
        deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
        properties={'bootstrap.servers': '10.234.175.22:9092', 'group.id': 'test'}
    )

    ds = env.add_source(kafkaSource).print()
    env.execute('kafkaread')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kafkaread()
```

But python doesnt recognise the jar file and throws the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flinkKafka.py", line 31, in <module>
    kafkaread()
  File "flinkKafka.py", line 20, in kafkaread
    kafkaSource = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
  File "/automation/flink/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/datastream/connectors.py", line 186, in __init__
    j_flink_kafka_consumer = _get_kafka_consumer(topics, properties, deserialization_schema,
  File "/automation/flink/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/datastream/connectors.py", line 336, in _get_kafka_consumer
    j_flink_kafka_consumer = j_consumer_clz(topics,
  File "/automation/flink/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 185, in wrapped_call
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Could not found the Java class 'org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer'. The Java dependencies could be specified via command line argument '--jarfile' or the config option 'pipeline.jars'
```

What is the correct location to add the jar file?

Comment: Are you using a maven build? or any other build?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you downloaded flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.13.0.jar, but the code loades flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.10.1.jar.

May be you can have a check

Answer (score 0):

just need to check the path to flink-sql-connector jar

Answer (score 0):

You should add jar file of flink-sql-connector-kafka, it depends on your pyflink and scala version. If versions are true, check your path in add_jars function if the jar package is here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).